# .NET 4.8 Web Application launchSettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I created a new project using a .NET 4.8 Web Application Template (Owin), and i added OpenIddict, but i cant seem to find a way to run it with iisexpress using the launchSettings i wrote

in the project i added a Startup.cs with a partial class Startup to configure the authentication

***Startup.cs***

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApp.Startup))]
namespace WebApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
...
```

where ConfigureAuth is declared in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

***App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs***

```cs
namespace WebApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
...
```

I noticed this project was created with an output type of

***WebApp.csproj***

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

so i tried to change it to Exe but it wont even build

here are my launchsettings:

***Properties/launchSettings.json***

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55946/",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

do i need to add something somewhere to tell the project to use this launchsettings?

the project starts correctly but with the default iis settings (no https, port 5000)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you happen to find the solution for this?

Comment: I just stopped using openiddict